# Infusionsoft Place order api showing No method matching arguments: java.lang.String, java.lang.Integer error

Tags: php, infusionsoft

I am working in infusionsoft place order api but getting this error.
No method matching arguments: java.lang.String, java.lang.Integer, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer
This is my code of api.

```
<?php
require_once("isdk.php");
$client = new xmlrpc_client("https://dv331.infusionsoft.com/api/xmlrpc");
###Return Raw PHP Types###
$client->return_type = "phpvals";
###Dont bother with certificate verification###
$client->setSSLVerifyPeer(FALSE);

class infusionsoft extends iSDK {

    public $appName, $information;  
    public function __construct() {
        include('conn.cfg.php');
        foreach ($connInfo as $appLine) {
            $nameIs['appName'] = substr($appLine, 0, strpos($appLine, ":"));
        }
        $this->appName = $nameIs['appName'];
        if ($this->cfgCon($this->appName)) {    
            //echo "You Are Connected To Infusionsoft !";               
        } else {
            echo "You Are Not Connected To Infusionsoft !";
            exit();
        }   
    }
}   
$app = new infusionsoft();
$carray = array(
  $key,
  @contactId,  
  $CreditId, 
  $planId, 
  array(100,101), 
  array(100,101), 
  false,
  array("MyPlan1","MyPlan2"));
  $result = $app->placeOrder($carray);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume from your code that old [Infusionsoft SDK](https://github.com/yugenekr/iSDK) is in use.

Than here's the source of the method placeOrder() you're calling:

```
/**
 * @method placeOrder
 * @description Builds, creates and charges an order.
 * @param int $contactId
 * @param int $creditCardId
 * @param int $payPlanId
 * @param array $productIds
 * @param array $subscriptionIds
 * @param bool $processSpecials
 * @param array $promoCodes
 * @param int $leadAff
 * @param int $saleAff
 * @return array
 */
public function placeOrder($contactId, $creditCardId, $payPlanId, $productIds, $subscriptionIds, $processSpecials, $promoCodes, $leadAff = 0, $saleAff = 0)
{
    $carray = array(
        php_xmlrpc_encode((int)$contactId),
        php_xmlrpc_encode((int)$creditCardId),
        php_xmlrpc_encode((int)$payPlanId),
        php_xmlrpc_encode($productIds),
        php_xmlrpc_encode($subscriptionIds),
        php_xmlrpc_encode($processSpecials),
        php_xmlrpc_encode($promoCodes),
        php_xmlrpc_encode((int)$leadAff),
        php_xmlrpc_encode((int)$saleAff));
    return $this->methodCaller("OrderService.placeOrder", $carray);
}
```

**Therefore, the first parameter to send is $contactId, API key is added implicitly.**

Sent parameters are also type-casted internally, so you shouldn't have any issues as long as correct parameters are provided.